# Error during composer install --no-dev option in ElasticBeanstalk with Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, composer-php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying Symfony 2 app in ElasticBeanstalk but when I run this I get an error saying

```
ERROR: Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle class not found.
```

I have this config.

```
container_commands: 
    110-remove-pg: 
    command: "yum remove -y php56-pgsql"

    120-install-pglib: 
    command: "yum install -y postgresql94-libs"

    130-install-pg: 
    command: "yum install -y php56-pgsql"

    140-clear-folder: 
    command: "rm -rf var/cache/* var/logs/* var/sessions/*"

    150-folder-config: 
    command: "source .ebextensions/bin/folder.sh"

    160-pre-cache-clear: 
    command: "php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug"

    170-run-export: 
    command: "export SYMFONY_ENV=prod"

    180-composer-install-no-dev: 
    command: "composer.phar install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader"

    190-post-cache-clear: 
    command: "php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug"

    200-assets-dump: 
    command: "php bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug"

    210-remove-dev-app: 
    command: "rm web/app_dev.php"
```

Seems like it is still triggering DEV option. If I remove --no-dev option it works fine. But I do not want DEV packages. Is there anyway to resolve this issue.

Comment: maybe you include SensioGeneratorBundle in AppKernel for every env (it should be included only for dev)


    `if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
        ...
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        ...
    }
`

Answer (score 1):

Alright I found the solution of this problem. Apparently you need to put

```
SYMFONY_ENV=prod
```

In environment variables list for this to work.